# Second Order Derivative of a function $f:R^2\to R^2$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

**The Exercise:**

[image: exercise]

**My Work:**

Part 1:
$$
Df=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
D_1f_1 & D_2f_1\\
D_1f_2 & D_2f_2 \\\end{array} \right)
$$
$$f_1(x,y)=\sin x+\sin y$$
$$f_2(x,y)=\cos x+\cos y$$
$$
Df(x,y)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos x & \cos y\\
-\sin x & -\sin y \\\end{array} \right)
$$

Part 2:

I don't know how to do part 2. How do I find the partial derivatives of the components of $Df(x,y)$?

Edit:

(Attempted solution, per user127645's answer)
$$D^{k+1}f = \begin{pmatrix} D_1(D^kf) & \bigg| & D_2(D^kf)\end{pmatrix}$$ 
$$D_1(D^1f)(x,y)=D_1\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos x & \cos y\\
-\sin x & -\sin y \\\end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\sin x & 0\\
-\cos x & 0 \\\end{array} \right) $$
$$D_2(D^1f)(x,y)=D_2\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos x & \cos y\\
-\sin x & -\sin y \\\end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\sin y\\
0 & -\cos y \\\end{array} \right) $$
$$D^2f(x,y)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\sin x & 0 & 0 & -\sin y\\
-\cos x & 0 & 0 & -\cos y \\\end{array} \right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with the book's treatment of $D^2f$ as a $2\times 4$ matrix; it should be a $2\times 2\times 2$ tensor. But no use arguing with bound leaves of paper. I would use the following inductive approach: once $D^kf $ is known, $D^{k+1}f$ is the block matrix 
$$D^{k+1}f = \begin{pmatrix} D_1(D^kf) & \bigg| & D_2(D^kf)\end{pmatrix}$$ 
Each of two blocks is obtained by differentiating every entry of $D^kf$ with respect to the corresponding variable (first or second).

Comment: Thanks user127645. I edited my question to include my attempted solution based on your response. Have I interpreted your answer correctly?

Comment: Yes this is what I had in mind. @jef