# Second derivative of f(x,y)

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I try do finde the Matrix $D^3f(a)$ where $f(x,y)=x^4-3x^3y^2$

What i tried is

$Df(x,y)=\left( \begin{array}{c}
4x^3-9x^2y^2 && -6x^3y\\
\end{array} \right)$

This is a $1\times 2 $ matrix.
Then following [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671945/second-order-derivative-of-a-function-fr2-to-r2)
I get:

$
D^2f(x,y)=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
12x^2-18xy^2 && -18x^2y && -18x^2y && -6x^3\\
\end{array} \right)
$

and

$
D^3f(x,y)=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
24x-18y^2 && -36xy^2 && -36xy && -18x^2 &&
36xy && -36x^2 && -18x^2 && -18x^3\\\\
\end{array} \right)
$

which is a $8\times1$ matrix. 
I have troubles by understanding how to get $D^rf(x,y)$ for arbitrary functions

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the Hessian?

Comment: No, I have a problem where the Hessian becomes zero and the first non-vanishing term is $D^4f(0,0)$ but I don't know how to compute $D^4f$

Comment: Well, do you necessarily need to write down $D^4f$? It should be enough to compute the $4$-th derivatives of $f$ at $(0,0)$ to see what you say, shouldn't it?

Comment: I ultimatly want to know if the function $f$ has a lokal extremum in $(0,0)$. For this i think need $D^4f(0,0)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your last comment: you can observe that $f(x,y) = x^3(x-3y^2)$. So in the half plane $x \geq 0$ you have that $f \geq 0$ if $x \geq 3y^2$ or $x=0$, otherwise $f < 0$. If $x < 0$, then $f$ is a sum of a non-negative and a positive term, so $f(x,y) > 0$. So $(0,0)$ is not a local extremum.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called the **Hessian** matrix. You can read more on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix).
Basically it allows you to have a matrix in which all of the variables of your multivariable function are partially derived. The Hessian for a 2 variable function with be: $$\pmatrix { \frac { \partial^2f }{\partial x^2 }& \frac {\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y} \\ \frac {\partial^2f}{\partial y \partial x } &\frac { \partial^2f }{\partial y^2}  }$$

Comment: When the second order derivatives vanish, I can't use the Hessian. In those cases I need the higher order derivative $D^rf$. I try to edit my question

Comment: I have $$
\nabla ^2f\left( x,y \right) =\frac{\partial ^2f\left( x,y \right)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2f\left( x,y \right)}{\partial y^2}
\\
\frac{\partial ^2f\left( x,y \right)}{\partial y^2} = f(x+1,y) - 2f(x,y) + f(x-1, y)
$$

Why we have $\frac{\partial ^2f\left( x,y \right)}{\partial y^2} = f(x+1,y) - 2f(x,y) + f(x-1, y)$ please?