# 4-th derivative of $f(x,y)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, maxima-minima

I want to know if 
$$f(x,y)=x^4-3x^3y^2+2x^2y^2-3x^2y^3+y^4$$
has a local minimum or maximumin in $(0,0)$

What i tried is find the first non-vanishing derivative $D^4f(0,0)$ and see if $D^4f(0,0)(h,...h)$ is positiv-/negative-/indefinite. My problem is that I could not calculate $D^4f(0,0)$. I tried to follow [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671945/second-order-derivative-of-a-function-fr2-to-r2) but then i get a $1\times16$ matrix for $D^4f$

Comment: $f(x,0)=x^4,$ so it doesn't have a local *maximum* at $(0,0).$  I think it has a local minimum, but I haven't been able to prove it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using polar coordinates, we have $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^2-3x^2y^2(x+y)=r^4(1-3r\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta (\cos \theta +\sin\theta))
$
so $f(x,y)\ge r^4(1-6r)$ for $r^2=x^2+y^2$. So $f$ can't be negative close to the origin, and $0$ is a local minimum.

Comment: I was just about to post a solution that does essentially the same thing by setting $y=ax.$ Polar coordinates was a good idea. +1